# multiple copy buffer profiles for vim?

Tags: vim

I try to make effective use of vim's copy buffers by assigning regularly used commands to each one; but there never seems to be enough of them. When editing an html doc for example I bind `</li><br>\n\t<li>` to the `"l` copy buffer, but when editing a bash script use the `"l` buffer for a bash specific command. So between sessions I continuously have to copy one command out for the other and re-save it in the buffer depending on what kind of file I am editing, never mind if I am editing one of each simultaneously, which is often enough to consider it a common occurrence.

Is there a way I can create profiles for different copy buffers and load them depending on what kind of file I am editing?

Comment: You might want to look at a snippets plugin or insert mode abbreviations/mappings. Regardless look at ftplugins.

Comment: I do use snipmate with a crazy number of snippets defined and used regularly, but for entering the most common commands that occur many multiple times while editing a single file I seem to prefer using the copy buffers; they seem for me faster (perhaps mere illusion?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `~/.viminfo` contains the copy buffers currently stored. I guess you could create a copy of it, say `~/.viminfo_html` with all your html shortcuts, and another named `~/.viminfo_bash` with all your scripting shortcuts and before you open vim you can set either one to be `~/.viminfo`.

It looks like `/.viminfo` gets loaded into memory by vim when it starts up, and so if you wanted to edit an html and a .sh file simultaneously making use of your two `~/.viminfo` files you could (I tried it and it works, even if you add new data to some previously assigned copy buffers, the data in other buffers of the previous `~/.viminfo` file loaded at vim startup but since changed are still available, but I did not test much or for long enough to see whether or not copy buffer data unchanged remains stable for the duration of a vim session) simply swap out the current `~/.viminfo` file for the alternate and open the document in a new vim session in a separate terminal session.

If the `.viminfo` file you need from one session to another is totally sporatic and unpredictable, then you could whip up a little script to prompt you to select which `.viminfo` file to rename before starting vim.

Comment: @scripts just about does what I want. I don't plan to run different vim terminals though to have different copy buffer/register profiles. But it is a big help that before firing up vim I can at least assign one saved configuration or the other depending on what kind of file I will start to edit.

Comment: The blind leading the blind.

Answer (score 2):

They are called "registers", not "copy buffers".

You really should use a proper snippet expansion plugin like [the original Snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim), [the forked Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), [the fashionable UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) or [the venerable XPtemplate](https://github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate).

I explain two less "advanced" methods [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25092956/546861).